# Parameter variable not getting appended

Tags: bash, shell, unix, siebel

i have a UNIX shell script where i am passing values in form of parameters.Everything seems working good , but not for one parameter , but i can see it printed with echo command.

Script-:

```
#!/bin/bash

admPath=$1
admdatatype=$2
admeaimethod=$3
admprefix=$4
gatewayname=$5
enterpriseName=$6
userId=$7
password=$8
admFilter=$9

echo "$admPath"
echo "$admdatatype"
echo "$admeaimethod"
echo "$admprefix"
echo "$gatewayname"
echo "$enterpriseName"
echo "$userId"
echo "$password"
echo "$admFilter"


srvrmgr -g "$gatewayname" -e "$enterpriseName" -s gepfdevss -u "$userId" -p "$password" -c "run task for comp ADMBatchProc with admpath="$admPath", admdatatype="$admdatatype", admfilter="'$admFilter'", admeaimethod=$admeaimethod, admprefix="$admprefix"" -b >> exportLOVStatus.out
```

As you can see i have one parameter called `admFilter` whose value i want to pass as `'[List Of Values Parent (UDA).Value]=\"XRX_TEST\"'` .

When i execute above script i can see **echo** result as below -:

**execution -:**

```
./exportLOV.sh "/global/u70/globepfdev/ADM" "LOV" "Upsert" "export_ADM" "gateway" "enterpriseserver" "user" "password" \''[List Of Values Parent (UDA).Value]=\"XRX_TEST\"'\'
```

Echo result -:

```
/global/u70/globepfdev/ADM
LOV
Upsert
export_ADM
gateway
enterprise
user
password
'[List Of Values Parent (UDA).Value]=\"XRX_TEST\"'
```

But as the command is executed for Server Manager after successfull connection . This `admFilter` parameter is not reading value . This is the output for `run task` command -:

```
run task for comp ADMBatchProc with admpath=/global/u70/globepfdev/ADM, admdatatype=LOV, admfilter=$admFilter, admeaimethod=Upsert, admprefix=export_ADM
```

You can see every other parameter have a value associated with it apart from `admFilter` . I am stuck because of this can anyone help me out . How can i pass value properly?? Thanks

Comment: I don't see how that could be. That's the result you would get if you'd written: `admfilter="'$admfilter'",`

Comment: @Barmar you are right i corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single quotes prevent variables from being expanded. You should be putting the single quotes inside the double-quoted string, so they'll be sent literally to the `srvrmgr` command, not outside it.

There's also no need to end the double quotes around each variable in the `-c` argument.

```
srvrmgr -g "$gatewayname" -e "$enterpriseName" -s gepfdevss -u "$userId" -p "$password" -c "run task for comp ADMBatchProc with admpath=$admPath, admdatatype=$admdatatype, admfilter='$admFilter', admeaimethod=$admeaimethod, admprefix=$admprefix" -b >> exportLOVStatus.out
```

See [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)